# Rewrite cgi script url to another

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, cgi, manpage

How can I redirect a file system directory to map it to an url ?

I have installed man2html on my web server to access man pages via a website.

```
apt-get install man2html
```

I found that it is a cgi script, it was installed in :

```
/usr/lib/cgi-bin/man/
```

After installation it was already accessible without neither problems nor configurations ..

```
http://myurl.com/cgi-bin/man/man2html
```

I would like to redirect

```
http://myurl.com/cgi-bin/man/man2html
```

to

```
http://myurl.com/manpages
```

Edit:
Here is the ls of the directory:

```
ls -al /usr/lib/cgi-bin/man
total 88
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Feb 28 03:28 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root  4096 Feb 27 11:29 ..
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 20672 Nov  2  2011 man2html
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  8250 Nov  2  2011 mansearch
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 19472 Nov  2  2011 mansec
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 19472 Nov  2  2011 manwhatis
```

Knowing that the same domain name is hosting a wordpress blog so in the .htaccess :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
RewriteRule ^manpages/?$ /cgi-bin/man/man2html [L]
```

And I made:

```
sudo service apache2 reload
```

It won't work!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing this?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^manpages/?$ /cgi-bin/man/man2html [L]
```

Comment: htaccess file in the root.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Please check my update in the question.

Comment: I meant put it in the document root htaccess file for your domain not the man folder.

Comment: Thanks but it wont work. I am still searching. I think that wordpress hta config could cause conflicts. I will update the question.